# Get error 'recv.getParameters is not a function' when use webrtc-streamer to play camera(rtsp) on web

Tags: frontend, camera, webrtc, rtsp

I use this below repository to play rtsp on web:
https://github.com/mpromonet/webrtc-streamer

In the test, it works fine. But when I deploy the website to customer's computer, some of the computers cannot play camera, but some works fine.
On the abnormal computers, Chrome/Edge has no error on the devtool, but Firefox shows an error like below:
[image: deploy]

I tried to play the camera url in VLC, it can play, but cannot work on the web.

Because I used EasyDarwin & FFmpeg to simulate camera boradcast local, so I try to end the service of these two, I find the same error on Firefox.
[image: test]

So, I'm confused. Obviously the customer's camera is OK, because it can works on some computer, but why others cannot works fine? Maybe it is the computer setting or ?

Can someone please help me, thanks a lot!